# Range formula last row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to grab the last cell for my average, so I have it pulling a count from column A since column A does not have blanks, and determines the stopping point for my other columns. This works for my range functions, but I keep getting a compile error for "Expected: end of statement" when I use the below.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("H2").Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE("H3:H" & lastrow), """")"
```

The output would be something like if column A had 200 lines, the forumla would input as =IFERROR(AVERAGE(H2:H200),"")

Comment: FWIW - In order to create the statement to produce the formula you **say** you want, you would take `=IFERROR(AVERAGE("H2:H200"),"")`, escape every `"` by using `""` to get `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(""H2:H200""),"""")`, and then replace `200` with `" & lastrow & "` to get `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(""H2:H" & lastrow & """),"""")` which can then be used as  `Range("H2").Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(""H2:H" & lastrow & """),"""")"`.  But Scott's answer gives you what you **actually** want.

Comment: Scott's answer is exactly how I said I wanted it. I simply had a quotation mark in the incorrect spot. Your answer is incorrect as it would output as =IFERROR(AVERAGE("H2:H200"),"") putting the range in quotation marks.

Comment: I realise that Scott's answer supplies you with what you actually want.  I was just showing you the steps you could have used to produce what your question **says** you wanted (i.e. `=IFERROR(AVERAGE("H2:H200"),"")`, so that you could use that process in future where you know the formula you want and need to generate a statement to produce it.

Comment: Ah, yeah. It was a typo on my behalf. I had copy and pasted and removed info. Just forgot to remove the extra ""s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `H2:H` is part of the string and not in `""`.

```
Range("H2").Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(H2:H" & lastrow & "), """")"
```

Comment: Oh jeez, yeah. I knew it was something simple. Thanks a lot!